# submiting data on same page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to submit the data in the same page.But it is not entering into the `if` statement.

so i made the form simple to test, but still its not happening. somebody please tell me where i am doing wrong.

When i hit Submit, it shows all the data in URL like this instead of printing `"hello"`

```
http://domainname/student_system/stud_attendance_report.php?stud_name=KUMAR+RAI&enroll_no=1993%2FVII%2FB%2F2003-2004%2F0&class=&section=&submit=Search
```

here is my form

```
<?php
include ("header.php");
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    echo "hello";
}
?>
<div id="container">

<form metohod="post" action="">
<input type="text" id="stud_name" name="stud_name" />
<input type="text" id="enroll_no" name="enroll_no" />
<input type="text" id="class" name="class" />
<input type="text" id="section" name="section" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: form "metohod" ? fix the typo

Comment: @Fopa Léon Constantin why did you fix OP's code? Do a rollback or I will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You spelled `method` wrong:

```
<form metohod="post" action="">
```

should be

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: "metohod" --- sounds like a new heavy metal band or a new H-D model.

Comment: `teh metohod` - heaviest meatl band ever!!!

Comment: I rather be listening to The Eagles on my H-D on a very long strip of highway ;-)

Comment: I have many fond memories of cruising home late at night with the windows open and rocking out. It's been too long since I've had an opportunity to do that.

Comment: It's time to get a convertible then. Say like a '64 Impala perhaps? ;-)

Comment: I'm hoping for a motorcycle before long. Just officially got my license last September. :)

Comment: Cool! You're going to have a great time then :) Riding in the countryside where I live is a treat on its own; I'm never moving back to the "la grande città". So, a full-dress Super-Glide perhaps? An 'ol pan/shovel/knuckle head? I rather a shovelhead myself hehe

Comment: I have a few friends who are eager to go for a cruise. In New Jersey where I'm at there isn't a whole lot of places where you can do just that (at least in a countryside environment) but we're not far from places in Pennsylvania where you can go for a nice ride in the countryside.

Comment: No doubt John. I've seen many a photos/videos etc. of those places, sounds great! I was in The Maritimes last year and met up with about 7-8 bikers who came from various US states, a few from Texas, another from Mississipi, another from South Carolina and a few more, and they absolutely LOVED the ride up there. They were so happy to find someone who spoke "English" lol "Hey man, finally somebody who talks English around here" (*said in a Southern accent*)... Many Maritimers speak French and only French, but I'm fluently bilingual and some Italian anche ;-)

Comment: I work with a biker. Definitely a culture all their own. :)

Comment: For sure. I used to "wrench" myself, wayyyy back. I'd be lost without my trusty 'ol 9/16" wrench lol (still have it though) I'm not just a "coder" you know ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I'm stealing that name for my next band.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Just as long as John and I get VIP backstage passes! lol - I'll bring my guitar ;-)

Comment: Count me in! I'll bring my bass!

Comment: Small world John; very cool. While I'm at it, may as well bring my mandoline, banjo and whatever else I can fit in hehe